# Risk of bond calculation

Tags: fixed-income, risk

I am studying a course and I am a bit confused on how to find the a bonds $\sigma$. My course mentions the following:
Once calculated the expected returns on the bond $\mathrm{E}(r_d)$, we can
calculate the debt beta:

$\mathrm{E}(r_d) = r_f + \beta_d(\mathrm{E}(r_M) − r_f))$

$\beta_d = \mathrm{E}(r_d − r_f)/\mathrm{E}(r_M − r_f)$

where $r_f$ and $r_M$ are the usual risk-free rate and market portfolio and where:

1. $\mathrm{E}(r_d)$: expected return on debt
2. $r_f$: return on riskless debt
3. $(\mathrm{E}(r_M) − r_f))$: return on equity market portfolio
   If we know the Beta of debt, we can estimate the volatility of
   debt:

$\beta_d = \rho(r_M, r_d) \times (\sigma_d/\sigma_M)$

$\sigma_d = (\beta_d \times \sigma_M)/\rho(r_M, r_d)$

There is still an assumption that needs to be made between the correlation between the market portfolio and debt. But I believe this is negative. If I use this formula and the $\beta_d$ is positive the $\sigma_d$ will be negative and this doesn't make sense to me. The only way that $\sigma_d$ is positive is if the  $\beta_d$ is negative. Am I wrong? Can someone please help me understand? Thanks

Comment: *[I believe] the correlation between the market portfolio and debt [...] is negative.* I don't agree with this. If the market goes up the price of risky debt also goes up (becomes less risky, moves away from default). To put it differently risky debt has an equity like behaviour over the economic cycle and thus a (small but) positive beta.

Comment: @nbbo2 I see what you mean. I assumed that bonds and equity had a negative correlation. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

the answer to your question really just boils down to the definition of correlation and regression Beta. You can not *mathematically* have a positive Beta and a negative correlation. This is mathematically impossible.

$\beta = \frac{cov(y,x)}{var(x)} = \frac{\rho \sigma_y \sigma_x}{\sigma_x^2}$.

i.e. $\beta = \rho \frac{\sigma_y}{\sigma_x} $.

Since volatilities are always positive the $\beta$ has the same sign as $\rho$.